# Create trigger to insert a column value into other column of same table SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

How to create trigger to insert a value in a column same as value of another column of same table of a newly inserted row in the table.

Suppose I have table like below

```
ColumnA | ColumnB
```

I want columnB value to be inserted into ColumnA as soon as row gets inserted into table or columnB value gets updated . But it should not be vice versa ie insert columnA value into columnB

.Below code handles INSERT only , please help me how to handle both **Insertion and Updation** of table ie when columnB value gets inserted or updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER inserupdate
   ON  triggertestTable
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    declare @value int

    select @value=columnB from inserted

    update triggertestTable
    set columnA=@value

END
GO
```

This works fine if values inserted like below

```
insert into triggertestTable(columnB) values('xyz')
```

ColumnB value gets inserted into columnA

```
ColumnA | ColumnB
  xyz   |  xyz
```

But null value gets updated in both if some other application inserts value in columnA

```
 insert into triggertestTable(columnA) values('pqr')
```

Now records are

```
ColumnA | ColumnB
  xyz   |  xyz 
  NULL  |  NULL
```

The correct recordset should be like below

```
  ColumnA   | ColumnB
      xyz   |  xyz 
      pqr   |  NULL
```

How to solve this problem.

Comment: If ColumnB gets updated then (1) ColumnA should be, also, updated or (2) ColumnA should be updated only if the old and the new values of ColumnB are different? What happens if are inserted values in both columns (ColumnA and ColumbB) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this trigger (it will copy the values from ColumnB to ColumnA when are inserted values into ColumnB or when are updated the values from ColumbB):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgIU_triggertestTable_UpdateColumnAWhenColumnB
   ON  dbo.triggertestTable
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(ColumnB)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  dbo.triggertestTable
        SET     ColumnA=i.ColumnB
        FROM    inserted i
        INNER JOIN dbo.triggertestTable t ON i.MyID=t.MyID
        LEFT JOIN deleted d ON i.MyID=d.MyID
        WHERE   d.MyID IS NULL AND i.ColumnB IS NOT NULL -- Row was inserted
        OR      d.MyID IS NOT NULL -- Row was updated
    END
END
GO
```

I used this table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.triggertestTable(
    MyID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, -- MyID should be a PRIMARY KEY or a mandatory(NOT NULL) UNIQUE constraint
    ColumnA VARCHAR(100),
    ColumnB VARCHAR(100)
);
GO
```

Comment: Note: at this moment, if a statement tries to insert data in both columns then ColumnA is overwritten with values from ColumbB. It's correct this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

`inserted` is a pseudo-table and may contain *multiple* rows. You should write something set-based. Something like:

```
 update triggertestTable
    set columnA=COALESCE(columnA,columnB)
where id in (select id from inserted)
```

(If `triggertestTable` has a primary key column called `id`)

The above sets `columnA` to `columnB`'s value, if `columnA` doesn't already have a value, which I think might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In your trigger, you have to update ColumnA only if ColumnB is not NULL.

Use the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER inserupdate
   ON  triggertestTable
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

    declare @id1 int

    select @value=columnB from inserted

    if @value is not null
    begin
        update triggertestTable
        set columnA=@value
    end
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks , works absolutely correct if Insert() statement gets excuted but if a row columnB value gets UPDATED then all the columnA value also get updated to same value ...

Comment: It works till are inserted two or more diff. values into ColumnB: `INSERT INTO triggertestTable(columnB) SELECT 'xyz' UNION ALL SELECT 'abc';`. Well, it could  ...

Comment: Well the main problem with this trigger is that it assumes there is only one row in `inserted` table. And this means that it assumes, also, that an {INSERT|UPDATE} statement affects only one row. For example, this statement might INSERT many rows: `INSERT ... (ColumnB) SELECT ... FROM ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
    update triggertestTable
    set columnA=@value
    where columnB is not NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a where clause to the trigger, otherwise it would update the whole table!

```
DECLARE @value int, @pkid int

SELECT @value = columnB, @pkid = pkid FROM INSERTED

IF @value IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE triggertestTable
    SET columnA = @value
    WHERE pkid = @pkid
END
```

Comment: See [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/), this has a fatal flaw in that it assumes that the `inserted` table has exactly one row